# Distribution that maximizes probability that sum of random variables equals a particular value

Tags: probability

I have independent random variables $x_i \in \{0,1\}$ with $p(x_i = 0) = p_i$. How can I find the distributions over $x_i$ (i.e. $p_i$'s) that maximize (for some positive integer $c$):
$$ p(\sum_{i} x_i = c)$$

Comment: Do you assume that $x_i$'s are  independent?

Comment: @SashaKozachinskiy Yes

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy In case the $x_i's$ are i.i.d, then $p(\sum_i x_i = c)$ reduces to a binomial distribution, for which the maximizing parameter I think can explicitly be written down (by differentiating).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Correct me if I am wrong, but: \begin{align*} \frac{d}{dp} \binom{n}{c} p^{c}(1-p)^{n-c} &= 0 \\ \Rightarrow cp^{c-1} (1-p)^{n-c} &= (n-c) p^c (1-p)^{n-c-1} \\ \Rightarrow p &= \frac{c}{n} \end{align*}

Comment: You are right. I was making a mistake and I have deleted my comment.

Comment: If you set exactly $c$ of the $p_i$ to be $1$, and then the remaining $p_i$ to be $0$, then the sum will equals to $c$ almost surely. (But in such case you may argue that they are no longer independent, so maybe you need to check if the problem is ill-posed?)